# How to make line plotted thicker in mschart

Tags: c#, mschart

I have a line which connects different points. I have generated the line dynamically. I want to make the line thinker.
My code is as below:

```
  //now lets plot lines between tow points.
 Series newLineSeries = new Series("LineSeries" + index);

 //--If the series already present lets remove from the chart 

 if(chart1.Series.IndexOf(newLineSeries.Name) != -1)
  {
  chart1.Series.RemoveAt(chart1.Series.IndexOf(newLineSeries.Name));
  } 
  newLineSeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
   newLineSeries.MarkerBorderWidth.Equals(15);
  newLineSeries.MarkerSize.Equals(35);

 newLineSeries.Color = menuStripNodeInfoValues[index].colorValue;  
 newLineSeries.ToolTip = tooltipString;//tooltipString is cal. dynamically

newLineSeries.Points.Add(new DataPoint(valueX1,valueY1)); //valueX1,valueY1 are some dynamically calculated values
newLineSeries.Points.Add(new DataPoint(valueX2,valueY2));//These are also also dynamically calculated
chart1.Series.Add(newLineSeries);
```

This successfully generate a line but the size of the line doesnot change even when i change the MarkerSize property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `chart1.Series[i].BorderWidth = 5` ? If by size you mean thickness